# Moving an Adapter Object from one activity to another

Tags: java, android, android-studio, adapter

I want to move an adapter object from one activity to another.

My main activity:

```
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ActivityTest.class);
                intent.putExtra("Key1", position);
                intent.putExtra("key2", toyAdapter);
                startActivity(intent);
```

My second activity:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
                int position = intent.getIntExtra("Key1", 0);
                ToyAdapter toyAdapter = (ToyAdapter) intent.getSerializableExtra("Key2");
```

I know something's wrong but I am pretty new to this and therefore I am not sure what's the right way to move that Adapter Object to my second activity. Thanks

Comment: You should really take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2736389/how-to-pass-an-object-from-one-activity-to-another-on-android

Comment: @hanut I tried looking at it already but it seems to not work for me. I thought it might have something to do with the object's type being an Adapter but I am not sure how to fix it

Comment: Is this a recycler view adapter that you want to pass between activities?